# difference between two comma separated strings

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) `yy`

```
    fundId  Year    Qtr   StockCurrentQtr    StockNextQtr
    1       2015    1     1,2,3,4,5         2,3,4,51
    1       2015    2     2,3,4,51          7,8,9,4,2
    1       2015    3     7,8,9,4,2         NA
    2       2015    1     10,11,14          14,16,19
    2       2015    2     14,16,19          20,21,45
    2       2015    3     20,21,45          NA
```

I want to know the difference between `StockNextQtr` and `StocCurrentQtr` for each row `group_by` `fundId` or the difference between successive rows for the column 'StockCurrentQtr' `group_by` `fundId`

```
yy <- yy %>% 
       group_by(fundId) %>% 
       mutate(StockDiff = apply(yy,2,function(x){
                    paste(setdiff(unlist(strsplit(x[5], split = ",")), unlist(strsplit(x[4], 
                                                            split = ","))),collapse = ",")}))
```

I am getting following error:

> Column StockDiff must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 5

Comment: Can you update your post with your expected output?

Comment: _Don't_ store your data in unnormalized CSV format like this.  It will usually cause problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `apply` here. Just `rowwise`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(4:5), funs(strsplit(., ','))) %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(new = toString(setdiff(StocCurrentQtr, StockNextQtr)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
> Groups: <by row>
>
> # A tibble: 6 x 6
>   fundId  Year   Qtr StocCurrentQtr StockNextQtr new          
>    <int> <int> <int> <list>         <list>       <chr>        
> 1      1  2015     1 <chr [5]>      <chr [4]>    1, 5         
> 2      1  2015     2 <chr [4]>      <chr [5]>    3, 51        
> 3      1  2015     3 <chr [5]>      <chr [1]>    7, 8, 9, 4, 2
> 4      2  2015     1 <chr [3]>      <chr [3]>    10, 11       
> 5      2  2015     2 <chr [3]>      <chr [3]>    14, 16, 19   
> 6      2  2015     3 <chr [3]>      <chr [1]>    20, 21, 45
> ```

The equivalent in base R,

```
mapply(function(x, y)toString(setdiff(x, y)), strsplit(df$StocCurrentQtr, ','), 
                                              strsplit(df$StockNextQtr, ','))

#[1] "1, 5"          "3, 51"         "7, 8, 9, 4, 2" "10, 11"        "14, 16, 19"    "20, 21, 45"
```

If `StockNextQtr` is missing, we can create it first and continue in the same manner as before, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 group_by(fundId) %>% 
 mutate(StockNextQtr = lead(StocCurrentQtr)) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(4:5), funs(strsplit(., ','))) %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(new = toString(setdiff(StocCurrentQtr, StockNextQtr)))
```

Comment: Than you very much for the answer. If the column 'StockNextQtr' does not exist, how to find the difference between successive rows using group_by on FundId?

Answer (score 1):

I found another way

```
yy <- yy %>% group_by(fundId, Year, Qtr) %>% mutate(new = paste(setdiff((unlist(strsplit(StockCurrentQtr,split = ","))), unlist(strsplit(StockNextQtr,split = ","))),collapse = ","))
```